# How to stop Activity from reloading when using Intent.createChooser() to launch a sharing menu?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-webview, android-sharing

I have a WebView which has an sharing icon at the bottom of the page.

When the user presses the icon, it launches a sharing menu:

```
chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(0), "Share via");
chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, SHARING_MENU);
```

After the sharing menu pops up, if the user presses Back button or clicks outside the sharing menu, it closes down but the **Activity restarts and the webpage reloads inside the webview.**

I want to stop it. I tried to implement to the following code inside onActivityResult, but it is not working

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // Check which request we're responding to
        if (requestCode == SHARING_MENU) {
            // Make sure the request was successful
            if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                webviewObj.stopLoading();
                this.finishActivity(SHARING_MENU);
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried adding - `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in the manifest file, but it does not work.

Please help !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple solution to this problem.

In the WebView's Activity, I added the UI initialization code inside the :-

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        if(savedInstanceState == null) {
            initUI();
        }           
    }
```

And this solved my problem :)